# How to use Chart.js to draw solid points

Tags: chart.js

I recently used Chart.js to draw charts on my web page. Now that I'm having a problem, I've read Chart.js's document and found no way to draw solid points. Does anyone have this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in the docs [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html) I believe you would want to use something like the below, just adding a backgroundColor to your data in the dataset:

```
var chartData = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [45, 25, 20, 10],
        backgroundColor: [
            '#ff6384',
        ]
    }]
};
```

I've not tested so you might need to do the borderColour as well:

```
var chartData = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [45, 25, 20, 10],
        backgroundColor: [
            '#ff6384',
        ],
        borderColor: [
            '#ff6384',
        ]
    }]
};
```

Pretty sure this is how I did it on my line graph (however i wanted a different border colour), if you still have issues let me know and i'll have a test

Comment: Yes,it works.I'm curious why there is not one property that can be set.

Answer (score 1):

I used `pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(153, 124, 194, 0.5)'` under each dataset to configure the background colour of the point.

You can find it here, under "Dataset Properties":
[https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html][1]

Answer (score 0):

The pointBackgroundColor is a better option than backgroundColor. Using backgroundColor will not achieve the desired result in all cases as it will change the background of other parts of a chart (e.g. the enclosed section of a radar graph) as well as the points. You probably won't want the same colour choice for both of these cases. You're more likely to want something like:-

```js
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(56, 99, 255, 0.2)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(56, 99, 255, 1)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(56, 99, 255, 1)',
```